# Device assignment in distributed tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I implemented the between-graph replication and asynchronous training according to the example at ‘https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed’.

Then, I set two servers and one worker as follows.

python dnn.py --ps_hosts=localhost:19000,localhost:18000 --worker_hosts=localhost:11000 --job_name=ps --task_index=0

python dnn.py --ps_hosts=localhost:19000,localhost:18000 --worker_hosts=localhost:11000 --job_name=ps --task_index=1

python dnn.py --ps_hosts=localhost:19000,localhost:18000 --worker_hosts=localhost:11000 --job_name=worker --task_index=0

I have three questions for distributed tensorflow.

Firstly, according to the tensorflow timeline of my program as shown below, **all the computing and variable updating operations** **are executed at** **ps nodes**, while the worker node is idle. This is confusing for me, since I thought the computing operation should be executed at worker nodes instead of ps nodes. Would someone help me on this?

[distributed tensorflow timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q9lu.png)

Secondly, **only CPU is assigned to servers by using tf.train.replica_device_setter** in my program. However, the operations execute both at CPU and GPU. What is the correct way to assign CPU/GPU to servers?

Last but not the least, if I start two servers and three workers, will the two servers save the same copy of parameters? Also, I wonder whether the three workers will update gradients of the same graph. Would anyone tell me?

p.s. 
I assigned devices to both servers and workers by using tf.train.replica_device_setter. However, in the example (https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed), there’s no device assignment to the local server. In my case, if I didn't assign devices to local server, there will be errors like:

“Operation was explicitly assigned to /job:ps/task:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 ...]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.”

My code:

```
def train():
tl = TimeLiner()
#get current servers
ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
#get current workers
worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts,
                                "worker": worker_hosts})
graph_options = tf.GraphOptions(enable_bfloat16_sendrecv=True)
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.3, allow_growth=True)
config = tf.ConfigProto(graph_options=graph_options, gpu_options=gpu_options, log_device_placement=False,
                        allow_soft_placement=False)
#start a server
server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                         job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                         task_index=FLAGS.task_index,
                         config=config)
if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":
    with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
        with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(ps_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:%d/device:CPU:0" % FLAGS.task_index,
                                                      worker_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:%d/device:GPU:0" % FLAGS.task_index,
                                                      cluster=cluster)):
            loss = ...
            global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
            train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
            summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
        hooks = [tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=FLAGS.max_steps)]
        total_training = 0
        graph_options = tf.GraphOptions(enable_bfloat16_sendrecv=True)
        gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.9, allow_growth=True)
        config = tf.ConfigProto(graph_options=graph_options, gpu_options=gpu_options, log_device_placement=False,
                                allow_soft_placement=True)
        with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                               is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                                               checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.log_dir,
                                               log_step_count_steps=100000,
                                               hooks=hooks,
                                               config=config) as mon_sess:
            mon_sess.run(init_op)
            options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
            run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

            while not mon_sess.should_stop():
                # run a training step asynchronously
                [_, tot_loss, step, summary] = mon_sess.run([train_op, loss, global_step, summary_op],
                                                            options=options,
                                                            run_metadata=run_metadata)

                fetched_timeline = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
                chrome_trace = fetched_timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format()
                tl.update_timeline(chrome_trace)
        tl.save('timeline.json')
```

Thanks in advance!

Ying

Answer (score 0):

You've probably heard of setting device with tf.Device(cpu:0) or something like that you set right before starting session. Tried that?

Comment: But I think this line of code will do the same thing as tf.Device(): "with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(ps_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:%d/device:CPU:0" % FLAGS.task_index, worker_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:%d/device:GPU:0" % FLAGS.task_index, cluster=cluster))". Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It probably is because you put your worker's flag index in ps task's index in your replica_device_setter?